Does the category of sets with quasi-finite maps appear in the literature?
Consider the category $\mathbf{Set}_f$ whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are maps with finite fibers. That is, a map $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism in $\mathbf{Set}_f$ iff for every $y \in Y$ the fiber $f^*(y)$ is a finite subset of $X$. Equivalently, for every finite subset $V \subseteq Y$ the preimage $f^*(V) \subseteq X$ is a finite subset. From this description it is clear that morphisms are stable under composition.
Question. Does this category appear in the literature? Is it relevant for some topic? Is it (or its dual category) equivalent to a category which is more commonly known?
I am not asking for places where maps with finite fibers are studied, but rather that mentioned category and its properties.
Having finite fibers is a condition that often appears in algebraic geometry and related branches, namely under the term quasi-finite morphism, see Stacks/01TC. But the terminology doesn't seem to be used for plain sets. The category is inspired by this answer.
Update. The terminology finite-to-one maps is also used in the context of manifolds (example) and in set theory (example), thanks Andreas Blass for the comment.
Here are some basic observations on the category $\mathbf{Set}_f$. It is a wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$. It has no terminal object (it must be $1$, but the unique map $X \to 1$ is not a morphism when $X$ is infinite). It has finite coproducts, but I assume it doesn't have coequalizers. We have a (non-cartesian) symmetric monoidal category $(\mathbf{Set}_f,\times,1)$, whose monoids are exactly those monoids $M$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ such that for every $m \in M$ there are only finitely many $a,b \in M$ with $m = a b$. It follows in particular that we can construct the "infinitary monoid algebra" $R[[M]]$ with the Cauchy product $(f * g)(m) = \sum_{ab=m} f(a) g(b)$, which is a generalization of the algebra of formal power series that we get for $M = (\mathbb{N}^n,+,0)$.

Isn't this just tthe subcategory of topological spaces, where all spaces have the cofinite topology?

I'm accustomed to calling maps with finite fibers "finite-to-one" and I know that other set-theorists have used this terminology, but I'm not sure how widespread it is. These maps come up often in the study of ultrafilters.  (In French literature, I've seen "finijectif", but again I don't know how common it is.)

It doesn’t have coequalizers. As a concrete example, the identity map and the successor map on $\mathbb{N}$ admit no coequalizer, since the coequalizer in $\mathbf{Set}$ is $1$.
